# Time Capsule port forwarding not working?

Tags: network, time-capsule, internet, airport

I'm developing an app, and one of the requirements is to connect to a computer with the URL scheme:

```
http://ip/~username/file
```

The problem, however, is that I can't connect to my Mac remotely.

Let's say my public IP is xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

I have a Time Capsule setup as my router, and I enabled port forwarding for port `24001`, mapping it to my computer's LAN IP, 10.0.1.10 (DHCP reservation).

So, I saved the settings in my Time Capsule, then attempted to connect like so:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24001/~charlescarver/file
```

That didn't work, so I tried just connecting the following way:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24001
```

Which game me the *Safari can't connect to the server.* error.

I double checked the Time Capsule, then made sure my machine's firewall was turned off, and tried again: no luck.

Finally, I ran a Port Scan test in Network Utility, and it wasn't seeing port `24001` as open at all.

So then I tried forwarding the port to a different computer, `10.0.1.100`, which showed it as closed also.

What am I doing wrong, exactly?

Comment: You were elsewhere on the internet and not on the net served by the Time Capsule when you tried connecting?

Comment: No, I was still on the TC's connection when attempting to connect.